# Redis Prefix Not Work For Single Word Iteration

Tags: redis, full-text-search, redis-search

```
{
                "id": 3693657,
                "datum": "2024-01-09T05:40:02.000Z",
                "datum_lang_f": "09.01.2024 05:40",
                "source_code": null,
                "grusel": [
                    "WEBEUR"
                ],
                "bild": "https://soap.energie-und-management.de:443/filestore/newsimgorg/MBI-Energie/Erneuerbare/erneuerbare_shutterstock_163982216_27217-CMYK-2sp_HI_500.jpg",
                "bild_info": "Quelle: Shutterstock",
                "titel": "Gasförderung stillgelegt/Der niederländische Energiemix verändert sich",
                "inhalt": "Auch die Niederlande müssen auf globale Energiemarktentwicklungen reagieren. Im Inland wurde zudem die umstrittene Gasförderung gestoppt. Die Niederlande suchen mehr denn je nach Lösungen für eine größere Energieunabhängigkeit. Vor Ort ergeben sich immer mehr Möglichkeiten, erneuerbare Energieträger zu nutzen. Der Energieimport aus Russland wurde Anfang 2023 praktisch eingestellt. Vor dem Ukrainekrieg importierten die Niederlande jeweils 25 bis 30 Prozent ihres Öls und Gases aus Russland, bei Kohle waren es mehr als 50 Prozent. Laut der EU-Statistikbehörde Eurostat stieg die Energieabhängigkeit der Niederlande von 46 Prozent im Jahr 2015 auf gut 68 Prozent im Jahr 2020.<br>&nbsp;<br>Die niederländischen Strompreise schwanken. Dies ist auch auf die unterschiedlichen energiepolitischen Maßnahmen der Regierung zurückzuführen. Die in der 2. Jahreshälfte 2022 auf 9 Prozent zurückgeschraubte Mehrwertsteuer auf Energielieferungen belief sich im vergangenen Jahr wieder auf 21 Prozent. Auch in diesem Jahr soll das so bleiben. 2022 kam eine Studie der De Nederlandsche Bank (DNB) zu dem Ergebnis, dass sich der Anstieg der Energiepreise nur moderat auf die Rentabilität der niederländischen Unternehmen auswirke. Ausnahmen bildeten die Metallindustrie und der Chemiesektor.<br>&nbsp;<br>Die Regierung hat angekündigt, die Energiepreisdeckelung von 2023 im Jahr 2024 nicht in dieser Form fortzusetzen. Dies wurde damit begründet, dass sich die Preise 2023 weitestgehend stabilisierten. Die am stärksten betroffenen Haushalte können jedoch den wieder eingerichteten, befristeten Energienothilfefonds anzapfen. Im Kalenderjahr 2023 galt noch eine Preisobergrenze von 0,40 Euro pro Kilowattstunde Strom und 1,45 Euro pro Kubikmeter Gas für eine Nutzung von maximal 2.900 Kilowattstunden beziehungsweise 1.200 Kubikmeter für Haushalte. Auch kleine und mittlere Unternehmen profitierten von einem Subventionssystem.<br>&nbsp;<br>Die Netzkosten sollen 2024 aber wieder stark in die Höhe gehen. Die niederländische Energieinfrastruktur muss überarbeitet und modernisiert werden. Bis zum Jahr 2050 soll die niederländische Stromerzeugung vollständig auf erneuerbare Energien umgestellt werden. Dieses Ziel wurde im Jahr 2021 insofern modifiziert, dass auch die Kernenergie eine Rolle bei der Erreichung der Klimaziele spielen soll, sowohl im Hinblick auf die Stromerzeugung in Ergänzung von erneuerbaren Energien als auch durch die Erzeugung von Wasserstoff. Aktuell planen die Niederlande für 2030 den Ausstieg aus der Kohleverstromung.<br>&nbsp;<br>Die umstrittenen unterirdischen Gasfelder bei Groningen im Norden der Niederlande wurden im Oktober 2023 stillgelegt. Eigentlich sollten die Gasfelder bereits 2022 geschlossen werden, doch nach dem Krieg in der Ukraine wurde noch eine Mindestmenge gefördert, um die bestehende Infrastruktur zu versorgen. Dafür könnte ein neues Gasprojekt auf den Plan rücken: Ein niederländisches Konsortium will eine Förderplattform nahe der Wattenmeerinseln Schiermonnikoog und Borkum errichten. In diesem Jahr könnte schon das erste Gas gefördert werden. Geplant ist eine Fördermenge von 2 bis 4 Milliarden Kubikmetern Erdgas pro Jahr.<br>&nbsp;<br>Die Niederlande verfügen über ein Kernkraftwerk in der Nähe von Borssele in der Provinz Zeeland. Nachdem die Kernenergie eigentlich abgeschaltet werden sollte, prüft die Aufsichts- und Genehmigungsbehörde ANVS aus sicherheitstechnischer Sicht, ob eine Laufzeit dieses Druckwasserreaktors über das Jahr 2030 hinaus möglich ist. Außerdem sind laut Gesellschaft für Anlagen- und Reaktorsicherheit (GRS) zwei neue Reaktoren geplant. Planung und Bau sollen durch den Staat mit rund 500 Millionen Euro bis 2025 und insgesamt 5 Milliarden Euro bis 2030 unterstützt werden. Für die Inbetriebnahme der neuen Blöcke wird das Jahr 2035 anvisiert.<br>&nbsp;<br>Ein rapider Ausbau von erneuerbaren Energien wird in den kommenden Jahren ausschlaggebend sein. Neben Biomasse und Windenergie zählt die Solarenergie zu den wichtigsten grünen Energieträgern. Im Jahr 2022 stieg die Leistung von Fotovoltaik gegenüber dem Vorjahr um rund 46 Prozent auf 16,8 Milliarden Kilowattstunden. Fast 60 Prozent davon entfielen auf gewerbliche Nutzung.<br>&nbsp;<br>Allerdings wurde laut Statistikamt CBS bei Privathaushalten das größere Wachstum registriert. Die Verbreitung des Net-Metering für kleine Fotovoltaikanlagen hat unter anderem dazu beigetragen. Bis 2030 sollen Anlagen mit einer Gesamtkapazität von 27 Gigawatt am Netz sein. So sieht es zumindest der Nationale Klima- und Energieplan von 2020 vor. Demnach sollen die Windkraftkapazitäten etwas mehr als 16 Gigawatt erreichen &ndash; davon etwa zwei Drittel Off- und ein Drittel Onshore. Die Niederlande wollen sich als Hub für den Transport von grünem Wasserstoff und deren Derivate positionieren. Ein Pipelinenetz von mehr als 1.200 Kilometern Länge soll Belgien und verschiedene deutsche Städte mit grünem Wasserstoff versorgen. Für 2030 ist der Start geplant.<br>MBI/GTAI/aul/9.1.2024",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "kategorie_id": 117,
                        "kategorie": "Europa",
                        "kategorie_eng": "Europe",
                        "gruppen_id": 0,
                        "gruppe": "",
                        "gruppe_eng": "",
                        "parentGroup": []
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Hi developers, Thankyou in advance here i have an issue with redis full text search suppose i want to search a word start with "gasp" so i create an query like that `FT.SEARCH idx:news "(@inhalt: gasp*) (@id: [3693657 3693657])"` but it don't return this document but if i use this query `FT.SEARCH idx:news "(@inhalt: gas*) (@id: [3693657 3693657])"` without p then it return because in the document there are many word start with gas but the word that are start with gasp are iterate only once so may it matter? the expected document which i provide with you above and the word "Gasprojekt" is present in @inhalt field so according to my first query it should return the document but not why?

Comment: Can you share what version of RediSearch are you using?

Comment: @A. Guy version that i use `redis_version:7.2.2`

Comment: Can you try running `FT.CONFIG SET MAXPREFIXEXPANSIONS 1000000` and `FT.CONFIG SET TIMEOUT 0` and test again, to check if the miss is caused by max expansion limitation or a timeout?